# Метод для взятия разрешения экрана

Tags: android, java

Мне нужно узнать разрешение экрана и разделить его на половину чтобы нарисовать квадрат.

Реализовал так:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawView(this));
  }

  class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private DrawThread drawThread;
    Paint p;
    Rect rect;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      getHolder().addCallback(this);
      p = new Paint();
      rect = new Rect();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
      drawThread.setRunning(true);
      drawThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      boolean retry = true;
      drawThread.setRunning(false);
      while (retry) {
        try {
          drawThread.join();
          retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }
    }

    class DrawThread extends Thread {

      private boolean running = false;
      private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private int height;
    private int width;

      public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
      }

      public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void MyScreenSize() {
      Point size = new Point();
      WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
          w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

          width = size.x;
          height = size.y;
      } else {
          Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
          width = d.getWidth();
          height = d.getHeight();
      }
      }

    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;

        while (running) {
          canvas = null;
          try {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            if (canvas == null)
              continue;
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
            // настройка кисти
            // красный цвет
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            // толщина линии = 10
            p.setStrokeWidth(10);

            // рисуем точку (50,50)
            canvas.drawPoint(50, 50, p);

            // рисуем линию от (100,100) до (500,50)
            canvas.drawLine(100,100,500,50,p);

            // рисуем круг с центром в (100,200), радиус = 50
            canvas.drawCircle(100, 200, 50, p);

            // рисуем прямоугольник 
            // левая верхняя точка (200,150), нижняя правая (400,200)
            canvas.drawRect(height, 150, width, 200, p);

            // настройка объекта Rect
            // левая верхняя точка (250,300), нижняя правая (350,500)
            rect.set(250, 300, 350, 500);
            // рисуем прямоугольник из объекта rect
            canvas.drawRect(rect, p);
          } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
              surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

При изменении конкретных координат точек (как было в учебнике) на данные этого метода получаю ничего, а именно квадрат вообще не рисуется. Eclipse ошибок не выявляет. Мне кажется, что ошибка именно в этом методе.

Comment: код для получения разрешения правильный. Видимо, не правильно рисуете квадрат...

Comment: Проверял, рисуется правильно,  как я говорил если указать конкретные цифры в параметре квадрата, то он спокойно отрисовывается

Comment: А где вызов MyScreenSize()? Добавьте его в конструктор потока. А вообще размеры тут надо брать из метода 

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
    int height) {

    }

Comment: А где конструктор потока?

Comment: public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
  }

Comment: Добавил:
public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        MyScreenSize();
      }
Вроде так надо,но не квадрат не появился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно размер экрана я беру так:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

Помогает при центрировании окон, думаю, поможет и здесь. Потом просто использовать методы getHeight() и getWidth()

Comment: Забыл сказать, мне на Android это нужно

Comment: А если так?
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

Comment: Все так же не появляется квадрат, может у меня с модификаторами проблемы или аргумент в скобки нужен?

Comment: Может быть, с выводом квадрата что-то не то? И я вижу у вас подавление Warning'а, то что метод Deprecated, вполне возможно, проблема в этом. Попробуйте запустить код пошагово, посмотреть где какие значения, что как отрабатывает

Comment: Я взял депрекативный потому что апи не позволяет использовать более новый

Answer (score 2):

```
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

        mWindowWidth = size.x;
        mWindowHeight = size.y;
    } else {
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        mWindowWidth = d.getWidth();
        mWindowHeight = d.getHeight();
    }
```

В mWindowWidth ширина в mWindowHeight вышина.

Comment: Кажется я нашел где проблема,либо поле не хочет отдавать параметрам квадрата значение переменной, либо сама переменная не отдает значение полю.Почему - не знаю. Помогите исправить, код всего класса выложил в тему

Answer (score 1):

Может вам поможет:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.Toast;

public  class ScreenInfo {

    private final String TAG = ScreenInfo.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String DENSITY_HIGH = "DENSITY_HIGH";
    public static final String DENSITY_MEDIUM = "DENSITY_MEDIUM";
    public static final String DENSITY_LOW = "DENSITY_LOW";
    public static final String DENSITY_UNKNOWN = "DENSITY_UNKNOWN";

    public static void getScreenType(Activity activity, Context context){


        if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Large screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Normal sized screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Small sized screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "Screen size is neither large, normal or small",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public static int getDensity(Activity activity, Context context){

        System.out.println(" TEST DENSITY FROM CONTEXT : "+context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        // Determine density
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int density = metrics.densityDpi;

        if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "DENSITY_HIGH... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH;
        } else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "DENSITY_MEDIUM... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
        } else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "DENSITY_LOW... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "Density is neither HIGH, MEDIUM OR LOW.  Density is "
                            + String.valueOf(density), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return -1;
        }

    }

    public static void getPexelSize(Activity activity, Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        System.out.println("Screen size: " + wt +"/" + ht + " px");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Screen size: " + wt +"/" + ht + " px", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public static int getWidthPixels(Activity activity, Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        int wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        return wt;
    }


    public static int getHeightPixels(Activity activity, Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        int ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

        return ht;
    }

    // Ширины экрана в dp
    public static int getSwDp(Activity activity){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int swDp = (int) ScreenHelper.convertPixelsToDp(wt, activity);
        return swDp;
    }

    // Высота экрана в dp
    public static int getShDp(Activity activity){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int shDp = (int) ScreenHelper.convertPixelsToDp(ht, activity);
        return shDp;
    }


}
```

**ScreenHelper.java**

```
public class ScreenHelper {

    private final String TAG = ScreenHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * This method converts dp unit to equivalent pixels, depending on device density.
     *
     * @param dp A value in dp (density independent pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into pixels
     * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
     * @return A float value to represent px equivalent to dp depending on device density
     */
    public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
        return px;
    }

    /**
     * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
     *
     * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into dp
     * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
     * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
     */
    public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi /160f);
        return dp;
    }

}
```